Blotchy stain job
my boyfriend and I just bought our first home and have been finishing the floors for 2 days now. After sanding, adding wood filler in gaps, and sanding again (box sander 36 grit + edger and hand sander) we finally got to a good place to start staining. Once we stained the first room and saw the result we quickly realized it looked horrible. Stain was incredibly blotchy around the whole room. Stain would dry quickly in areas and once we began to stain under a section you could clearly see a line from where we had just stained no matter how quickly we worked. We believed this was heart pine (floors are 117 y/o) but now not sure. Any advice?
https://imgur.com/a/4NOyKv9

I strongly recommend a trip to the [woodworking.se] sister site and a review of the [stain], [finishing], and [refinishing] tags, as well as a search for "blotchy stain". There's a wealth of knowledge there that will explain what you're seeing. TL;DR: That's what pine does...

You didn't say what the wood was. Pine is notoriously prone to absorbing stain unevenly; degree of sanding can affect absorption in all woods. You may be looking at sanding it all down again to remove the blitches.
Applying a sanding sealer before staining can help control this. Basically that involves applying shellac, letting it soak in, and then sanding off the top layer. This fills the pores in the wood and limits stain to mostly going through the actual wood cells.
A glaze (tinted varnish) rather than a stain can be another way to limit blotching, but doesn't enhance the wood grain the way stain can.
Practice on a scrap of the same material or in an inconspicuous  corner before staining an entire piece of furniture -- or an entire floor.
Reminder: stain is not paint. Normally you apply it, let it soak in a bit, and then rub most of it off again so only the stain which was actually absorbed remains. If you want to apply an even tint over the entire surface, you're back in the domain of glazes.
Note that traditional oil-based varnish has an overall yellow glaze effect; water-based polyurethane dries clear. In some areas I actually used shellac for its yellow tone, applying layers until it was a reasonable approximation to the surrounding wood, before applying water-based poly as the protective layer.
